# Should functions be declared as macros if I use macros the same way in c?

Tags: c, macros, naming-conventions

If I make, for example, generic resizable list, which has `list_init(type)` function-like macro and I want to create `list_add(void*)` function, which doesn't need to be a macro, should I define it as a macro as well to be consistent? Also, if I have different naming conventions for macros and functions, should they in this case use the same one?

Comment: I recommend you don't use macros at all, and instead only make functions.

Comment: It should be the other way around: if it can be a function, don't make it a macro. And if you have different naming conventions, stick to it.

Comment: There is a MISRA rule only for function like macros: Rule 4.9: Don't use function like macros wherever using a function instead creates similar result.